# Reverse Y axis in MapProxy TMS source

Tags: wms, tile-map-service, mapproxy

As seen on the screenshot, my MapProxy reverses Y axis and I can't figure why.

MapProxy.yaml:

```
services:
  demo:
  tms:
    use_grid_names: true
    # origin for /tiles service
    origin: 'nw'
  kml:
      use_grid_names: true
  wmts:
  wms:
    md:
      title: MapProxy WMS Proxy
      abstract: This is a minimal MapProxy example.

layers:
  - name: gisdb
    title: gisdb WMS
    sources: [gisdb_cache]

caches:
  gisdb_cache:
    grids: [osm_grid]
    sources: [gisdb_tms]
    disable_storage: true

sources:
  gisdb_tms:
    type: tile
    url: http://localhost:1234/styles/positron/%(z)s/%(x)s/%(y)s.png
    transparent: true

 grids:
    webmercator:
        base: GLOBAL_WEBMERCATOR
    osm_grid:
        base: GLOBAL_MERCATOR
        srs: 'EPSG:3857'
        origin: 'sw'
globals:
```

I've tried changing `origin:` to `sw` , `nw` or `'nw'`, but that didn't help at all. Caching is disabled. I'm using https://github.com/klokantech/tileserver-gl

[image: wrong tile order]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to add a grid specification to your tiles source, e.g.:

```
sources:
  gisdb_tms:
    type: tile
    url: http://localhost:1234/styles/positron/%(z)s/%(x)s/%(y)s.png
    transparent: true
    grid: webmercator
```